# Virtual Network Interfaces Going up and down every 15 seconds

Tags: networking, fedora, kvm

This is the output from `dmesg` on the host machine, for some reason after the vm's have been running for a while their networking just starts cutting out every 15 seconds.

Host machine is running the latest version of fedora server, i have 1 vm running Debian and 1 running fedora server. both experience cutting out.

```
[121918.311653] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
[121918.311695] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered disabled state
[121920.679189] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
[121920.679206] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered blocking state
[121920.679210] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered listening state
[121927.860286] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
[121927.860321] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered disabled state
[121930.705401] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
[121930.705419] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered blocking state
[121930.705424] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered listening state
[121945.905176] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered learning state
[121955.704447] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link down
[121955.704489] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered disabled state
[121958.555435] r8169 0000:05:00.0 enp5s0: link up
[121958.555451] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered blocking state
[121958.555454] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered listening state
[121974.062092] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered learning state
[121989.420397] workingbridge0: port 4(enp5s0) entered forwarding state
[121989.420405] workingbridge0: topology change detected, propagating
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely is a bad cable. Look for a dog chewing on it, or other physical damage.

It's also possible that the NIC is bad, or the switch port on the other end is bad.

You should switch out hardware until you isolate the defective part.